# How to add selected values of a datagridview column to a variable and use that variable to update database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I have just started using c#. I am currently working on a small stock management application in which I have a form for creating a new purchase order.

[image]

my code for data from adding selected rows to a database that contains the purchase orders is

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    bool isSelected = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["Select"].Value);
    if (isSelected)
    {
        String constring = "server=Localhost;user id=root;password=sql1997;database=jpt";
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constring))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO jpt.Order VALUES(@pno,@Partno,@pdate,@balance)", con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pno", TxtPOn.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Partno", row.Cells["Part_No"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pdate", DatePicker.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@balance", row.Cells["Quantity"].Value);

                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        inserted++; //to show in message box
    }
}
```

For each selected row I need to use the value in the field "Quantity" to update rows in another table called 'Parts' corresponding to value of field "Part_Number"

For example

I Have entered quantity 5 For `Part_Number 433369`. This 5 has to be added to a field balance in another table `Parts` as `balance=balance+5`

I tried using the code below but it is not working

```
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("update jpt.parts set balance = balance + @qty", con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", row.Cells["Quantity"].Value);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Can someone suggest anything else?

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your query `"update jpt.parts set balance = balance + @qty", con)`. It might just be me but never seen an update query like this. You might want to check on **joint statements** instead.

Comment: Can you explain how it is not working (are you seeing an error message, incorrect values, wrong rows being updated) and what you want the desired outcome to be, please?

Comment: Values are updated incorrectly. But I'm not getting any error messages. I think the error might be with this statement : cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", row.Cells["Quantity"].Value); . qty is supposed to store an integer value. In that case do I need to covert the object  "row.Cells["Quantity"].Value"  to an integer??

Comment: The sql statement `update jpt.parts set balance = balance + @qty` will apply to all rows in the table. It needs a `WHERE` clause restricting it to the `Part_number` you are interested in updating

Comment: @Amruta Can you be specific with what you mean with `Values are updated incorrectly`. Are they being updated, too many rows updated, too few, incorrect value?

Comment: I added the "where" clause as you suggested. Now I am getting a different error. If I have selected multiple rows in the form above then it only updates for the last Part_Number in the last row selected.(though it is updating the value correctly)